# Weird output printing arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, memory, char, cs50

I decided to do the CS50 course again and tried to go about solving some of the problems differently. There is a task where you have to print pyramids with two spaces between each half using the '#' char with a height determined by the user (should be between 1 and 8 though). If the height was 4 it should look like this for example:

```
   #  #
  ##  ##
 ###  ###
####  ####
```

This works fine when the integer is anything between 1 and 7 but when it is 8 it starts adding gibberish non-ascii characters to the right of the left half of the pyramid.

This is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int h = 0;
    while (h < 1 || h > 8) {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &h);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        char a[h + 1];
        char b[h - (h - i) + 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {

            a[j] = h - j > i + 1 ? ' ': '#';
            if (i <= j) b[i] = '#';
        }
        printf("%s  %s\n", a, b);
    }
}
```

I thought it might be a memory thing so I just set the size of the char arrays to 3000. It stopped printing gibberish and still worked fine for heights 1 - 7 but when the user put anything more than 7 the pyramid looked skewed like this:

```
          #
       #  ##
      ##  ###
     ###  ####
    ####  #####
   #####  ######
  ######  #######
 #######  ########
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thank you to everyone who responded! The problem was that I didn't set null terminators in the string. This is the working function:

```
int main(void)
{
    int h = 0;
    while (h < 1 || h > 8) {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &h);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        char a[h + 1];
        char b[h - (h - i) + 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {

            a[j] = h - j > i + 1 ? ' ': '#';
            if (i <= j) b[i] = '#';
        }
        a[h] = '\0';
        b[h - (h - i) + 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s  %s\n", a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are few issues with your code.

1. You are initializing arrays a and b inside the loop. This means that the arrays are created with different sizes for each iteration, causing unpredictable behavior.
2. When you print the arrays using %s, it expects null-terminated strings. However, the arrays a and b might not be null-terminated.
   To fix this, you can modify your code to use a single array for each row and adjust the printing logic. Try the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int h = 0;
    while (h < 1 || h > 8) {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &h);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        char row[2 * h + 3];  // Maximum required size for the row

        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * h + 2; j++) {
            if (j < h - i || (j >= h && j < h + 2) || j > h + i + 1) {
                row[j] = ' ';
            } else {
                row[j] = '#';
            }
        }
        row[2 * h + 2] = '\0';  // Null-terminate the string
        printf("%s\n", row);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re “This means that the arrays are created with different sizes for each iteration, causing unpredictable behavior”: There is nothing unpredictable about that. The size is evaluated each time execution reaches the declaration, and the array’s lifetime is associated with the enclosing block, so there is a new array in each loop iteration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The problem is for example that each new variable length array b created in the outer for loop actually will not necessary contain the same values assigned to the array in preceding iterations of the loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The code shows the intent is to set the values in each array on each iteration of the outer loop, not to reuse values between iterations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It seems the array b needs to keep values assigned in previous iterations of the loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: That would be an alternate solution, but it is not the intent of the original code. OP’s code is written to initialize each array in each iteration on `i`, using a loop on `j`, and its only error in that regard is accidentally swapping `i` and `j` in the assignment to `b`. If they had intended to keep the arrays, the code would have been very different.

Comment: You were right about the null terminator, thank you!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Due to this assignment if (i <= j) b[i] = '#'; b[0] will be set to '#' only in the first iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, because `i` and `j` were accidentally swapped, as I said. Taking OP’s intent as defining `a` and `b` in each iteration, the only correction that needs to be made in that regard is changing `if (i <= j) b[i] = '#';` to `if (j <= i) b[j] = '#';`. Taking OP’s intent as keeping `a` and `b` between iterations, you would have to make multiple changes to the code. When somebody on the street asks you where the library is, they probably mean the library in the neighborhood, not the library in another city. The closer goal is the one more likely intended.

Answer (score 3):

You have made this way more complicated than it needs to be.

First of all, you don't need to store the blanks in the same string as the hashes; you don't need to store the blanks at all.

Allow me to introduce you to a couple of powerful tools in the `printf` arsenal: the field width and precision specifiers.  Given the line

```
printf( "%10.3s\n", "Hello" );
```

the output would be (`_` represents a blank):

```
_______Hel
```

`10` specifies the entire field width, `3` represents the maximum number of bytes to print from the string.

Even better, those values don't have to be hardcoded; you can use placeholders in the format string and pass those values as arguments:

```
 int w = 10, p = 3;
 printf( "%*.*s\n", w, p, "Hello" );
```

Hopefully you can see the utility in this immediately:

```
 for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
   printf( "%10.*s\n", i, "Hello" );

 _________H
 ________He
 _______Hel
 ______Hell
 _____Hello
```

Bonus trick: you can left-justify the output with a `-` in the conversion specifier:

```
 for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
     printf( "%-10.*s\n", i, "Hello" );
```

gives you

```
 H_________
 He________
 Hel_______
 Hell______
 Hello_____
```

So you only need to build the string once, for whatever the maximum width needs to be:

```
size_t size;
if ( scanf( "%zu", &size ) != 1 )
  // bad input, bail out here

char a[size+1];  // +1 for 0 terminator
memset( a, '#', size );
a[size] = 0;
```

and then use the width and precision specifiers to display the pattern as required.

Comment: What is the point? A student is learning to deal with bugs in their code, and, instead of teaching them how to find bugs, what their code means in contrast to what they think it means, or what errors they made (so they can fix their ideas), we give them alternate code using concepts they are not working on learning now? Is that really useful? Is the question they asked “Solve this assignment for me?” or “Help me figure out these things I am trying to learn?”

Comment: @EricPostpischil The point is to show different approaches, and this certainly provides value.  Personally, I think `printf` is completely the wrong way to solve this problem, but it's nice to see a solution that goes the opposite direction and uses `printf` more fully.   The student benefits from seeing multiple approaches to a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd say the point is in the first sentence: "You have made this way more complicated than it needs to be."  That directly answers the OP's *Why is this happening and how can I fix it?*  The OP wrote overly complex code that was too hard to understand when it didn't do exactly as designed, and the fundamental fix is to learn to not write overly-complex code that you can't understand when it does something wrong.  That's a fundamental basis for writing working code no matter what specifics are being taught, and hopefully the OP learns this lesson well after all the time spent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “You have made this way more complicated than it needs to be”: Yes, that is something students should learn. But that is a later concept; they cannot implement it until they know both the easy way and the complicated way. This answer takes away learning opportunities. It presents a new solution, not exercising concepts the student was working on, that leaves the student prone to making the same mistakes. It does not tell them they need to null-terminate their array. (It does show code that null terminates the array but does not explain why that has to be done…

Comment: … In the original, the student did not null-terminate their two character arrays, likely indicating they either believed the arrays would automatically initialized or they neglected this. In either case, their attention should be called to this.) It is well intentioned to want to teach the students good concepts, but they need to get there in steps. You cannot make first-year computer science students write clean code by teaching them the notion they should not write complicated code. They need to learn step by step.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: And all of that is assuming Stack Overflow ought to be providing tutorials at all, instead of answering specific questions. The question asked specifically was “Why is this happening and how can I fix it?”, and this post does not answer it.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height = 0;
    while (height < 1 || height > 8) {
        printf("Height: ");
        // really should check the return value here...
        scanf("%d", &height);
    }

    // start from 1 because we're always
    // printing at least one # on each side
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        // number of # chars is same as current
        // iteration value
        int hashChars = i;

        // pad each row to line them up
        int leadingBlanks = height - i;

        // print the necessary leading blanks
        for (int j = 0; j < leadingBlanks; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        // print the left side # chars
        for (int j = 0; j < hashChars; j++) {
            printf("#");
        }

        // two spaces to separate left and right sides
        printf("  ");

        // print the right side # chars
        for (int j = 0; j < hashChars; j++) {
            printf("#");
        }

        // go to next line for next row
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The major points here:

1. [Keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and don't try to solve the entire problem all at once.
2. Use variable names that make it clear what the variable means
3. There's no attempt to be "clever" or "fast", just understandable
4. There's no cramming as much functionality into as few lines as possible

And the result?  Something that's much easier to understand and get working properly.  Critically, you don't have to try wracking your brain to figure out where to write what character in an array that changes size with each loop.

**After** it's working properly, only **then** you might take extra time to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate `a` and `b` with a null character. Merely defining the arrays, with `char a[h + 1];` and `char b[h - (h - i) + 2];` does not initialize them. Put `a[h] = '\0';` and `b[i+1] = '\0';` before the `printf`.

You do not fill `b` with `#` characters. `if (i <= j) b[i] = '#';` puts a `#` only in element `i`, which is constant inside the inner loop. You should have `if (j <= i) b[j] = '#';`.

Comment: The b array is correctly filled though as is

Comment: @vaultdweller: No, it is not. `if (i <= j) b[i] = '#'` only writes to `b[i]`, and `i` does not change in the loop on `j`, so it fills in only a single element of `b`.

Comment: Then why is the pyramid printed correctly?

Comment: @vaultdweller: It is not with the compiler I use. It may be the compiler you are using happens to store `b` in the same location in each iteration on `i`, so that the element that was set to `#` in the previous iteration remains set in the next iteration. This can happen if the compiler allocates memory for `b` first from the same starting point each time, whereas mine may allocate memory for `a` first, and the varying size of `a` thus forces `b` to move. In any case, as far as the specification of the C language is concerned, `char b[h - (h - i) + 2];` creates a new instance of the array…

Comment: … each time it is reached in execution, and the elements of that array are *indeterminate* (a technical term in the C standard), with the consequence that the C standard does not specify what values will be used. So the code is wrong and should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've neglected the principle of KISS.

```
#   define MAX_DIM 8 // <== NB

    int h = 0;
    while (h < 1 || h > MAX_DIM ) { // <==
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &h);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        char a[ MAX_DIM + 1 ] = { 0 }; // initialise entire array to `0` each loop.
    //  char b[h - (h - i) + 2];  // what?
        char b[ MAX_DIM + 1 ] = { 0 };

        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            a[j] = h - j > i + 1 ? ' ': '#';
            if (i <= j) b[i] = '#';
        }
    //  a[h] = '\0'; // terminating byte already contains '\0'. Too much code
    //  b[h - (h - i) + 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s  %s\n", a, b);
```

There's no reason to use variable length arrays to solve this beginner's problem. There's no reason for *clever* code to calculate the dimension of `b[]`.

OP challenge: move the definition of the tiny (initialised) arrays *outside* the loop, then set the appropriate element of each (one character only) to `'#'` before printing.

Comment: Test code before you post it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This answer was intended to show the OP how to NOT use the _advanced_ feature of VLAs. Applying this simplification reveals the a _hidden_ problem with the OP's code.... SO policy is "one question per question." You object to other answers, here, that depart from the OP's  method... Can't have it both ways...

Comment: Re “This answer was intended to show the OP how to NOT use the advanced feature of VLAs”: Really? That is not an error that caused their incorrect output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The OP seems to think that merely adding more code (terminating the arrays) fixes their problem. Your answer, here, suggests that solution is "implementation dependent"... If you choose to codone obfuscated code without comment, that's your privilege, naturally...

Comment: Adding code to terminate the arrays does fix their problem of the arrays not being null-terminated. They also need to fix the `i` and `j` swap. My answer does not in any way suggest the solution has any implementation dependency.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "_Adding [more] code..._" You said it...

Answer (score 0):

The strings you construct for printing are not null terminated, so the behavior is undefined when you pass them to `printf` for the `%s` format.  Depending on the initial contents of the uninitialized arrays, the output may appear as expected or different... and any side effect may happen such as a program crash or anything worse. The behavior is undefined and this explains why you observe erratic output for some input and not others, in fact nothing can be expected.

Here is modified version of your code with simpler loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int h = 0;
    while (h < 1 || h > 8) {
        printf("Height: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &h) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
        char a[h + 1];
        char b[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < h - i; j++) {
            a[j] = ' ';
        }
        for (int j = h - i; j < h; j++) {
            a[j] = '#';
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            b[j] = '#';
        }
        a[h] = '\0';
        b[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s  %s\n", a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the code is still complicated.  You can use the *width* and *precision* modifiers in `printf` to get a more concise solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int h = 0;
    for (;;) {
        char buf[80];
        printf("Height: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &h) == 1 && h >= 1 && h <= 8)
            break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
        const char *s = "########";  // up to 8 #
        printf("%*.*s  %.*s\n", h, i, s, i, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love your solution but have to say that, to me, mine seems much simpler

Comment: @vaultdweller: I see your point. `printf` is a very powerful function with lots of interesting options.  It takes some time and effort to master.  The second version also has better error handling and recovery.